# Maximum subscription limit of Kafka Topics Per Consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

What is maximum limit of topics can a consumer subscribe to in Kafka. Am not able to find this value documented anywhere.

If consumer subscribes 500000 or more topics, will there be downgrade in performance.

Answer (score 3):

500,000 or more topics in a single Kafka cluster would be a bad design from the broker point of view. You typically want to keep the number of topic partitions down to the low tens of thousands.

If you find yourself thinking you need that many topics in Kafka you might instead want to consider creating a smaller number of topics and having 500,000 or more keys instead. The number of keys in Kafka is unlimited.

Answer (score 2):

To be technical the "maximum" number of topics you could be subscribed to would be constrained by the available memory space for your consumer process (if your topics are listed explicitly then a very large portion of the Java String pool will be your topics). This seems the less likely limiting factor (listing that many topics explicitly is prohibitive).

Another consideration is how the Topic assignment data structures are setup at Group Coordinator Brokers. They could run out of space to record the topic assignment depending on how they do it.

Lastly, which is the most plausible, is the available memory on your Apache Zookeeper node. ZK keeps ALL data in memory for fast retrieval. ZK is also not sharded, meaning all data MUST fit onto one node. This means there is a limit to the number of topics you can create, which is constrained by the available memory on a ZK node.

Answer (score 1):

Consumption is initiated by the consumers. The act of subscribing to a topic does not mean the consumer will start receiving messages for that topic. So as long as the consumer can poll and process data for that many topics, Kafka should be fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

- Consumer is fairly independent entity than Kafka cluster, unless you are talking about build in command line consumer that is shipped with Kafka
- That said logic of subscribing to a kafka topic, how many to subscribe to and how to handle that data is upto the consumer. So scalability issue here lies with consumer logic
- Last but not the least, I am not sure it is a good idea to consumer too many topics within a single consumer. The vary purpose of pub sub mechanism that Kafka provides through the segregation of messages into various topics is to facilitate the handling of specific category of messages using separate consumers. So I think if you want to consume many topics like few 1000s of them using a single consumer, why divide the data into separate topics first using Kafka.